# HTML outer and inner table with different border color using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table inside another table. Styles of both tables are defined in CSS. I want inner and outer table with different border color. But somehow inner table is taking border color of outer table. Below is the code -

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" class="OuterTableStyle1"><tr><td>
    <table width="100%" class="CommonTableStyle1" >
            <tr>
                <th>Title 1</th>
                <th>Title 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>Data 1</td>
                 <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*======= Start : Common data table style =========*/
table.CommonTableStyle1 td
   {
   vertical-align:middle;
   padding:5px;
   font-size:11px;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-weight:normal;
   color:#000000;
   }

table.CommonTableStyle1 th, table.CommonTableStyle1 td
   {
   border: 1px solid #525272    ;
   }

table.CommonTableStyle1
   {
   border-collapse:collapse;
   }
/*======= End : Common data table style =========*/


/*=== Start : This table is used as border of another scrollable table ===*/
table.OuterTableStyle1 
   {
   border-collapse:collapse;
   }
table.OuterTableStyle1 th, table.OuterTableStyle1 td
   {
   border: 1px solid red;
   }
/*=== End : This table is used as border of another scrollable table ===*/
```

Please help.

**[Edited CSS]**

```
/*======= Start : Common data table style =========*/
table.CommonTableStyle1 td
   {
   vertical-align:middle;
   padding:5px;
   font-size:11px;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-weight:normal;
   color:#000000;
   }

table.CommonTableStyle1 th, table.CommonTableStyle1 td
   {
   border: 1px solid #525272    ;
   }

table.CommonTableStyle1
   {
   border-collapse:collapse;
   }
/*======= End : Common data table style =========*/


/*=== Start : This table is used as border of another scrollable table ===*/
table.OuterTableStyle1 
   {
   border-collapse:collapse;
   border: 1px solid red;
   }
/*=== End : This table is used as border of another scrollable table ===*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector

```
table.CommonTableStyle1 table, th, td
```

doesn't work properly, because there is no table in the table with class "CommonTableStyle1".

I think you meant to do this:

```
table.CommonTableStyle1 th, table.CommonTableStyle1 td
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3zFKJ/)

Also, the bottommost selector did work, but not in the way you may think. The `th, td` part had the same specificity as the one above, so it would take this style for all `th`s and `td`s, because this one came later. But it's OK now, since we've made the specificity of the above one larger.

Comment: Hi Mr. Lister, your answer worked for me. But if I change the code as shown in in my question, again same thing happening. Can you please help me to resolve this.

Comment: The code in the edited css section worked. Thanks Mr. Lister for pointing out my mistake.